# Reducing some cumbersome code for simplicity

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, mapply

I have a sample of my data as follows (real data is nearly .5 million women of childbearing age): In this dataset, I have a parity of women that consists of all children a woman has). This row continues until 30 children (ageownchild_pernum1: ageownchild_pernum30). For example, a woman has 2 children, This woman has 30 rows (filled with the age of the children) but only the first and second rows are filled with the age of the children the woman has, and other rows are filled with NA. Here I bring just two of the rows and omit others for simplicity.

```
library("tidyverse")
DataSet1<-
tibble(
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
ageownchild_pernum1 = c(18,24,13,16,9,NA,17,13,32,7 ),
ageownchild_pernum2=  c(16,NA,9 ,10,7,NA,13,11,20,5 ),
AGE=  c(38,52 ,41 ,43 ,38 ,36 ,40 ,36 ,56,31),
F_curve_notch_15= c(25.14,30.28,43.33,43.33,25.14,25.14,25.14,25.14,67   ,33.77),
F_curve_notch_15.25= c(34.01,40.33,51.74,51.74,34.01,34.01,34.01,34.01,73.85,41.91),
f_curve_tilde_15= c(25.14,30.28,43.33,43.33,25.14,25.14,25.14,25.14,67   ,33.77),
f_curve_tilde_15.25= c(25.14,30.28,43.33,43.33,25.14,25.14,25.14,25.14,67   ,33.77),
)
```

F_curve_notch and f_curve_tilde are for ages (15 to 49,.25).

Now, I want to do this bulky procedure on my data that may reach more than a thousand lines of code.

```
DataSet1$low_notch      <-ifelse((DataSet1$ageownchild_pernum1>=0),DataSet1$AGE - 
DataSet1$ageownchild_pernum1 - 0.75,0)
DataSet1$high_notch     <-ifelse((DataSet1$ageownchild_pernum1>=0),DataSet1$AGE - 
DataSet1$ageownchild_pernum1 + 0.75,0)
DataSet1$low_low_notch  <-ifelse((DataSet1$ageownchild_pernum1>=0),DataSet1$AGE - 
DataSet1$ageownchild_pernum1 - 1.25,0)
DataSet1$high_high_notch<-ifelse((DataSet1$ageownchild_pernum1>=0),DataSet1$AGE - 
DataSet1$ageownchild_pernum1 + 1.25,0)
DataSet1$low_low_notch  <-ifelse ((DataSet1$low_low_notch>=20)   & (DataSet1$low_low_notch<35)  
,DataSet1$low_low_notch+0.25,DataSet1$low_low_notch)
DataSet1$high_high_notch<-ifelse ((DataSet1$high_high_notch>=20) & 
(DataSet1$high_high_notch<35), DataSet1$high_high_notch+0.25, DataSet1$high_high_notch)

notch <- function(a, b,c,d){
ifelse((a<= 15)&(b>=15)&(c!= 0),0.01*d,c)
}
DataSet1$f_curve_notched_15<-mapply('notch',DataSet1$low_low_notch, DataSet1$high_high_notch, 
DataSet1$f_curve_notched_15,DataSet1$f_curve_tilde_15, DataSet1$f_curve_notched_15)
```

This procedure, should continue for all ageownchild_pernum(1:30) and  f_curve_notched(15 to 49, .25). I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverfow Azam MIrzaei and thanks for already providing sample data! In your `DataSet1`, which variable identifies the individual woman? (I'm asking because it might be advantageous to reshape your data from "wide" to "long" to have one row per child, and one column identifying the mother.

Comment: Hi Azam! Welcome! Am I right to assume that the DataSet1$ageownchild_pernumn>=0 checks are to see if the columns are empty?

Comment: also, it seems like you're storing two types of data in this dataframe- the birth-related information (ageownchild_pernum(1:30)) and then the fcurve-related ones ( f_curve_notched(15 to 49, .25)) which I assume is related to the age of the mother. Would you be able to confirm?

Comment: You show how the `low_notch` etc. columns are calculated based on `ageownchild_pernum1`. What should happen with `ageownchild_pernum2` etc. Would you overwrite the `low_notch` etc. columns or make `low_notch2` etc.?

Comment: Thank you. Here every "id" represents a woman. The number of children each woman has is represented by "ageownchild_pernum", which in real data continues until 30 children. if a woman has a child, column "ageownchild_pernum", refers to her child's age; therefore, DataSet1$ageownchild_pernumn>=0 checks to find out if the columns are empty or have a child.

Comment: Dear Mark(@Mark), I am so sorry for the confusion that I have caused. (ageownchild_pernum(1:30)) is the number of children that a woman has. f-curve-related information has been created from "asbrs" (the cohort birth history) for all ages and with linear interpolation based on the available values and ages for 15.25, 15.5, .....

Comment: Dear @TimTeaFan, we have to repeat all of these procedures, to modify "f_curve_notched" for all age groups from 15, 15.25, 15.5,.....49

Comment: @TimTeaFan, they have to be overwritten, but the "notch" that they are providing should be used to change the "f_curve_notched"

Comment: ah so the fcurve data would be the same for every row for a particular age group? ?

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible using several pivots to have all your f_curve ages and all your child columns compared to each other in one run:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DataSet1<-
  tibble(
    id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
    ageownchild_pernum1 = c(18,24,13,16,9,NA,17,13,32,7 ),
    ageownchild_pernum2=  c(16,NA,9 ,10,7,NA,13,11,20,5 ),
    AGE=  c(38,52 ,41 ,43 ,38 ,36 ,40 ,36 ,56,31),
    f_curve_notch_15= c(25.14,30.28,43.33,43.33,25.14,25.14,25.14,25.14,67   ,33.77),
    f_curve_notch_15.25= c(34.01,40.33,51.74,51.74,34.01,34.01,34.01,34.01,73.85,41.91),
    f_curve_tilde_15= c(25.14,30.28,43.33,43.33,25.14,25.14,25.14,25.14,67   ,33.77),
    f_curve_tilde_15.25= c(25.14,30.28,43.33,43.33,25.14,25.14,25.14,25.14,67   ,33.77),
  )

notch <- function(a, b,c,d){
  ifelse((a<= 15)&(b>=15)&(c!= 0),0.01*d,c)
}



dat_out <- DataSet1 |>
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("f_curve"),
    names_to = c("marker", "age_cat"),
    names_pattern = c("f_curve_(.*)_(.*)")
  ) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = marker, values_from = value) |> 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("ageownchild"),
    names_to = "child_n",
    values_to = "child_age",
    names_prefix = "ageownchild_pernum"
  ) |> 
  filter(!is.na(child_age)) |> 
  mutate(
    low_notch = child_age - 0.75,
    high_notch = child_age + 0.75,
    low_low_notch = child_age - 1.25,
    high_high_notch = child_age + 1.25,
    low_low_notch = if_else(low_low_notch>=20 & low_low_notch<35, low_low_notch+0.25, low_low_notch),
    high_high_notch = if_else(high_high_notch>=20 & high_high_notch<35, high_high_notch+0.25, high_high_notch),
    f_curve_notch = notch(low_low_notch, high_high_notch, notch, tilde)
  )

dat_out
#> # A tibble: 34 × 12
#>       id   AGE age_cat notch tilde child_n child_age low_notch high_notch
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1     1    38 15       25.1  25.1 1              18     17.2       18.8 
#>  2     1    38 15       25.1  25.1 2              16     15.2       16.8 
#>  3     1    38 15.25    34.0  25.1 1              18     17.2       18.8 
#>  4     1    38 15.25    34.0  25.1 2              16     15.2       16.8 
#>  5     2    52 15       30.3  30.3 1              24     23.2       24.8 
#>  6     2    52 15.25    40.3  30.3 1              24     23.2       24.8 
#>  7     3    41 15       43.3  43.3 1              13     12.2       13.8 
#>  8     3    41 15       43.3  43.3 2               9      8.25       9.75
#>  9     3    41 15.25    51.7  43.3 1              13     12.2       13.8 
#> 10     3    41 15.25    51.7  43.3 2               9      8.25       9.75
#> # ℹ 24 more rows
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: low_low_notch <dbl>, high_high_notch <dbl>,
#> #   f_curve_notch <dbl>
```

This will mean each woman will have a row for every combination of child and f_curve age bracket. These can be pivoted back to wider dataset to have one column per woman if needs be:

```r
dat_out |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(child_n, age_cat),
    values_from = f_curve_notch,
    names_prefix = "f_curve_notch_"
  )
#> # A tibble: 34 × 13
#>       id   AGE notch tilde child_age low_notch high_notch low_low_notch
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1     1    38  25.1  25.1        18     17.2       18.8          16.8 
#>  2     1    38  25.1  25.1        16     15.2       16.8          14.8 
#>  3     1    38  34.0  25.1        18     17.2       18.8          16.8 
#>  4     1    38  34.0  25.1        16     15.2       16.8          14.8 
#>  5     2    52  30.3  30.3        24     23.2       24.8          23   
#>  6     2    52  40.3  30.3        24     23.2       24.8          23   
#>  7     3    41  43.3  43.3        13     12.2       13.8          11.8 
#>  8     3    41  43.3  43.3         9      8.25       9.75          7.75
#>  9     3    41  51.7  43.3        13     12.2       13.8          11.8 
#> 10     3    41  51.7  43.3         9      8.25       9.75          7.75
#> # ℹ 24 more rows
#> # ℹ 5 more variables: high_high_notch <dbl>, f_curve_notch_1_15 <dbl>,
#> #   f_curve_notch_2_15 <dbl>, f_curve_notch_1_15.25 <dbl>,
#> #   f_curve_notch_2_15.25 <dbl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you are expecting?

```
left_join(
  DataSet1 %>% 
    select(id, AGE, starts_with("ageownchild_pernum")) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c(id,AGE)) %>% 
    mutate(
      low_notch = ifelse((value>=0),AGE - 
                           value - 0.75,0),
      high_notch = ifelse((value>=0),AGE - 
                            value + 0.75,0),
      low_low_notch = ifelse((value>=0),AGE - 
                               value - 1.25,0),
      high_high_notch = ifelse((value>=0),AGE - 
                                 value + 1.25,0),
      low_low_notch = ifelse ((low_low_notch>=20)   & (low_low_notch<35)  
                              ,low_low_notch+0.25,low_low_notch),
      high_high_notch = ifelse ((high_high_notch>=20) & 
                                  (high_high_notch<35), high_high_notch+0.25, high_high_notch)
    ),
  
  full_join(
    DataSet1 %>% 
      select(id, starts_with("F_curve_notch_")) %>% 
      pivot_longer(-id, values_to = "F_curve_notch_") %>% 
      mutate(name = str_remove(name, "F_curve_notch_")),
    
    DataSet1 %>% 
      select(id, starts_with("f_curve_tilde_")) %>% 
      pivot_longer(-id, values_to = "f_curve_tilde_")%>% 
      mutate(name = str_remove(name, "f_curve_tilde_")),
    by = c("id", "name")
  ) %>% 
    rename(curve_id = name),
  by = "id",
  relationship = "many-to-many" # consider other by specifications if necessary
) %>% 
  mutate(notch_result = notch(low_low_notch, high_high_notch, F_curve_notch_, f_curve_tilde_))
```

And the last columnn contains the `notch()` results:

```
# A tibble: 40 × 12
      id   AGE name                value low_notch high_notch low_low_notch high_high_notch curve_id F_curve_notch_ f_curve_tilde_ notch_result
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1    38 ageownchild_pernum1    18      19.2       20.8          18.8            21.5 15                 25.1           25.1         25.1
 2     1    38 ageownchild_pernum1    18      19.2       20.8          18.8            21.5 15.25              34.0           25.1         34.0
 3     1    38 ageownchild_pernum2    16      21.2       22.8          21              23.5 15                 25.1           25.1         25.1
 4     1    38 ageownchild_pernum2    16      21.2       22.8          21              23.5 15.25              34.0           25.1         34.0
 5     2    52 ageownchild_pernum1    24      27.2       28.8          27              29.5 15                 30.3           30.3         30.3
 6     2    52 ageownchild_pernum1    24      27.2       28.8          27              29.5 15.25              40.3           30.3         40.3
 7     2    52 ageownchild_pernum2    NA      NA         NA            NA              NA   15                 30.3           30.3         NA  
 8     2    52 ageownchild_pernum2    NA      NA         NA            NA              NA   15.25              40.3           30.3         NA  
 9     3    41 ageownchild_pernum1    13      27.2       28.8          27              29.5 15                 43.3           43.3         43.3
10     3    41 ageownchild_pernum1    13      27.2       28.8          27              29.5 15.25              51.7           43.3         51.7
# ℹ 30 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

**APPENDED**

If you need a wider data shape you can append the above listed code with:

```
%>%  
  transmute(id, AGE, f_curve_ = paste0(name, "_", "f_curve_", curve_id), notch_result) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("id", "AGE"), names_from = f_curve_, values_from = notch_result, names_sort = T)
```

You will get something like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 6
      id   AGE ageownchild_pernum1_f_curve_15 ageownchild_pernum1_f_curve_15.25 ageownchild_pernum2_f_curve_15 ageownchild_pernum2_f_curve_15.25
   <dbl> <dbl>                          <dbl>                             <dbl>                          <dbl>                             <dbl>
 1     1    38                           25.1                              34.0                           25.1                              34.0
 2     2    52                           30.3                              40.3                           NA                                NA  
 3     3    41                           43.3                              51.7                           43.3                              51.7
 4     4    43                           43.3                              51.7                           43.3                              51.7
 5     5    38                           25.1                              34.0                           25.1                              34.0
 6     6    36                           NA                                NA                             NA                                NA  
 7     7    40                           25.1                              34.0                           25.1                              34.0
 8     8    36                           25.1                              34.0                           25.1                              34.0
 9     9    56                           67                                73.8                           67                                73.8
10    10    31                           33.8                              41.9                           33.8                              41.9
```

Comment: Thank you Dear @asd-tm, I really appreciate your help. How can I turn my dataset to pivot_wider format?

Comment: @AzamMirzaei Please kindly look at the 'appended' part of my answer